# Use Docker Compose to create multiple containers

Tags: docker, sonarqube, docker-compose, sonarqube-ops

I am completely new to Docker. I have a sonarqube image. I wrote a sample Docker Compose file and ran the image. Everything is working fine. Now I want to create 5-6 containers using Docker Compose.

How can I do this?

This is my sample YAML file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
     - my_image
   my_image:
    image: mySonarApp
```

I also would be interested in knowing if it is possible to create them only with my docker config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add more service definitions

```
version: '2'
services:
  weba:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

  weba:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"

  webc:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9002:9000"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scale command to create more instances of the service:

`docker-compose scale web=6`